# How to register radio StateChange event using C++ WinRT API

Tags: c++, asynchronous, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

```
// Register
event_token StateChanged(TypedEventHandler<Radio, IInspectable const&> const& handler) const;
```

Can anyone please help with the code to register the events using C++ winRT. I'm looking for the code which can call the event when the radio state is changed

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please help with the code to register the events using C++ winRT.

You could refer to [official sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BluetoothLE/cppwinrt/Scenario1_Discovery.cpp#L122), and Register event like the following.

```
myRadioStateChangedToken = MyRadio.StateChanged({ get_weak(), &Scenario1_Discovery::MyRadio_StateChanged});
```

For more detail about Handle events by using delegates in C++/WinRT. please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events).

Comment: I'm tried with the  code 
auto rad1=rad.StateChanged({ get_weak(), &OnNetworkStatusChange });
where OnNetworkStatusChange is a void function 
I'm getting a error . Can you please help me in this

Comment: OnNetworkStatusChange has two parameters,

Comment: void OnNetworkStatusChange(){
//print statement}
OnNetworkStatusChange is the function defined by me 
the function is return type void

Comment: Please use this line  `void MainPage::Radio_StateChanged(Windows::Devices::Radios::Radio const& sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args)`

Comment: void Radio_StateChanged(Windows::Devices::Radios::Radio const& sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args) {}
Radio r;
auto myRadioStateChangedToken = r.StateChanged({Radio rad , &page_name::Radio_StateChanged });
I'm getting error for get_weak/radio_rad

Comment: That's not even valid C++. You presumably want something like `auto myRadioStateChangedToken = r.StateChanged({this , &page_name::Radio_StateChanged });`

Comment: I'm getting error in "this" what actually "this" refers in the code.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is that you need a better understanding of the C++ language. The code examples assume you are in the context of a non-static member function, which is what provides the `this`. From other code fragments, it seems that you are even trying to write statements that aren't enclosed in any function at all. I would focus first on getting a good grasp of C++.

Comment: void  Radio_StateChanged(Windows::Devices::Radios::Radio const& sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args) {
 DebugMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL_INFO, TRUE, L"\t Radio_StateChanged \n");
void init(){
auto radio = Radio::StateChanged(**xxx**, &Radio_StateChanged);} I'm not getting what should be written in **xxx**

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void Radio_StateChanged(Radio const& sender,
                        winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args) {
    printf("\t Radio_StateChanged \n");
}
    
void radio_register_function() {
    // retrieve all radios in the system
    IVectorView<Radio> radios3 = Radio::GetRadiosAsync().get();

    for (Radio const& radio : radios3) {
        // trying to get mobilebroadband object
        if (radio.Kind() == RadioKind::MobileBroadband) {
            // registering for event
            auto rad = radio.StateChanged(&Radio_StateChanged);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any compilation error but when I try to enable or disable the radio, the function `Radio_StateChanged` is not called (event not triggered).

Comment: Thank you :) I tried with the code but the function RadioStateChanged is not triggered whenever I try to on/off radio state.  Is there any other way to call and register the event radio.StateChanged()

Comment: Note the part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radio.statechanged) that explains: *"When a USB Bluetooth radio is removed or otherwise goes offline, no state change is reported."* Is this what's happening here?

Comment: No I'm just trying to enable and disabling airplane mode but still I'm not able to get the print message from the function Radio_StateChanged() //void Radio_StateChanged(Radio const& sender,                      winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& args)

Comment: If you debug the program, you'll see that the problem isn't the event at all. The problem is that `GetRadiosAsync()` returns no radios. Try recompiling as a 64-bit app.

Comment: I have radios present. If I try to get all the radios kind present I'll get WIFI, Bluetooth. Tried to add the method SetStateAsync() and  changed the state PROGRAMATICALLY from OFF to ON then the event notification is called but If I try to do the same by enabling/disabling the Bluetooth radio using windows setting (User interface) NO event notification is called. Please suggest should I add any other methods to call the event if state is changed via windows setting